# How to just continue if an array index is out of range?

Tags: rust

Let's say that I have this array - `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` - and I try to access an index that doesn't exist (Let's say 6). It would normally through an error. But is there any way that I can just completely ignore that error and continue like nothing happened?

Comment: Any reason you don't want to check if the index is >= the length of the array?

Answer (score 5):

Arrays (`[T; N]` with a fixed size `N` known at compile time) can be freely coerced into slices (`[T]` with a variable length known at runtime), so when you have an array you have access to the wide array of [`slice` methods](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html).

For your use case, [`slice::get`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.get) returns an [`Option<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html). If the index is valid you get `Some(value)`, and if it's invalid you get `None`.

Example:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let index = 6;

if let Some(value) = array.get(index) {
    println!("Found {} at array[{}]", value, index);
}
else {
    println!("array[{}] is out of bounds", index);
}
```

Output:

```
array[6] is out of bounds
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=559418b537b2c6df6273afcbee4e6c24)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If the array index is negative, you will get a compile time error because it have to be of type `usize`.

If its positive, you could compare it with the length of the array.

To handle an out of bounds index (like 6 in this case), you could do something like:

```
fn get_item(input_array: &[i8; 5], index: usize) -> i8 {
    if index >= input_array.len() {
        -1
    } else {    // continue
        input_array[index]
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_get_item() {
    assert_eq!(get_item(&[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2), 3, "Value at index 2 is 3");
}

#[test]
fn test_get_item_out_of_bounds() {
    assert_eq!(
        get_item(&[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 6),
        -1,
        "Array index out of bounds"
    );
}
```